# How long can BIOS update take?

Tags: bios, firmware, flashing

I have Asus X-570 E-Gaming.
The mobo was showing green Q-LED today, I came to know it's because of failed boot. So, I'm updating the BIOS(firmware or host boot software). The size of the flash file is 32 MiB and the flash drive used is 2.0 one. It's been 42 min now and the green LED(which indicates the BIOS is being flashed) still hasn't gone off, and now I'm worried. What to do?

For reference:

- Asus X570 E-Gaming
- GSkill RipJaws 32 GiB DDR4 @ 3200MHz
- Ryzen 5 3600
- Samsung 980 Pro PCIe4 SSD
- DeepCool 850W PSU
- Zotac RTX 3090 Trinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using it as my server and had no screen attached. When I finally attached the screen, it showed me that it was `CPU fan error`. I connected the CPU fan, but probably didn't connect it in the right set of pins so the POST wasn't going ahead, as soon as I did, the system worked. Why the BIOS update failed, however, I still can't figure out.
Thank you everyone for your support.

Comment: CPU fan error does not mean it wont work. You can just go to BIOS > Monitor > CPU Fan Speed > Set to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

It's an hour since you asked, and that's definitely too long for a normal BIOS update.

So, what to do: I would take a chat with [Asus support](https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/ROG%20Strix%20X570-E%20Gaming/HelpDesk_knowledge/)

Unless they come up with anything clever, I'd say you'll have to give up that BIOS update and hope you still have a working computer (most likely you'll get back to where you started this morning).

If so, start by checking what the Q-LEDs are actually telling you, by reading [ASUS motherboard troubleshooting via Q-LED indicators](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1042678) and taking the action described.

Only if the Q-LED troubleshooting doesn't help, they're bringing up the topic of BIOS clearing or flashing. If you need to try that, then make sure you follow the instructions given on that page, and chat with Support if you get stuck.

Comment: The update did not go through, I turned off the power and now I'm back to where I started. It shows a green LED which is for boot problems, what to do?

Comment: By the actions they suggest (under D), they seem to think it may be a bad connection to the boot disk (or a faulty disk). Is it possible for you to get to the disk and just disconnect and reconnect it again? Try to carefully clean the connector. No soap or water or hard objects, just very carefully remove any dirt you can see. And be careful with static electricity. Touch ground before you get close to the electronics. If you can get hold of any air-in-a-box, for use on electronics, then use that.

Comment: For air-in-a-box, check https://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Air-Dusters/b?node=3012916011. Fast moving air generates static electricity, so you need something that's designed for cleaning electronics.

Comment: It's solved, it was a simple error, I had no screen attached to couldn't see it. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In the video
[How to update the BIOS on Asus X570 Motherboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t36ttKl3kM4)
the update took about half a minute.
So something is wrong.

Verify first that you are using the latest BIOS from ASUS from
[ROG Strix X570-E Gaming - BIOS & FIRMWARE](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-x570-e-gaming-model/helpdesk_bios).

For more information on correctly installing the BIOS see the ASUS article
[How to update BIOS of the motherboard ?](https://rog.asus.com/support/FAQ/1044348)

Ensure that you are following exactly the procedure as described.

If the problem still happens, then you might have a hardware problem.

Comment: It's solved, it was a simple error, I had no screen attached to couldn't see it. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: So this was truly a "hardware" problem.